# debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)

Tags: json, swift, struct, decodable

I want to load an online json file into my application, but I am running into this error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array,
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
> "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.",
> underlyingError: nil))

I have looked on stackoverflow but other sollutions didn't help to solve mine.

My JSON:

```
{
  "copyright" : "NHL and the NHL Shield are registered trademarks of the National Hockey League. NHL and NHL team marks are the property of the NHL and its teams. © NHL 2022. All Rights Reserved.",
  "totalItems" : 0,
  "totalEvents" : 0,
  "totalGames" : 0,
  "totalMatches" : 0,
  "metaData" : {
    "timeStamp" : "20220813_172145"
  },
  "wait" : 10,
  "dates" : [ ]
}
```

My datamodel:

```
import Foundation

struct Initial: Codable {
    let copyright: String
    let totalItems: Int
    let totalEvents: Int
    let totalGames: Int
    let totalMatches: Int
    let wait: Int
    let dates: [Dates]
}

struct Dates: Codable {
    let date: String
    let totalItems: Int
    let totalEvents: Int
    let totalGames: Int
    let totalMatches: Int
    let games: [Game]
}

struct Game: Codable {
    let gamePk: Int
    let link: String
    let gameType: String
    let season: String
    let gameDate: String
    let status: Status
    let teams: Team
    let venue: Venue
    let content: Content
}

struct Status: Codable {
    let abstractGameState: String
    let codedGameState: Int
    let detailedState: String
    let statusCode: Int
    let startTimeTBD: Bool
}

struct Team: Codable {
    let away: Away
    let home: Home
}

struct Away: Codable {
    let leagueRecord: LeagueRecord
    let score: Int
    let team: TeamInfo
}

struct Home: Codable {
    let leagueRecord: LeagueRecord
    let score: Int
    let team: TeamInfo
}

struct LeagueRecord: Codable {
    let wins: Int
    let losses: Int
    let type: String
}

struct TeamInfo: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let link: String
}

struct Venue: Codable {
    let name: String
    let link: String
}

struct Content: Codable {
    let link: String
}
```

and here is my viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class TodaysGamesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var todaysGamesURL: URL = URL(string: "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule")!
    
    var gameData: [Dates] = []
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadTodaysGames()
    }

    func loadTodaysGames(){
        print("load Games")
        
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.frame = view.bounds
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        
        let todaysGamesDatatask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: todaysGamesURL, completionHandler: dataLoaded)
        
        todaysGamesDatatask.resume()
    }
    
    func dataLoaded(data:Data?,response:URLResponse?,error:Error?){
        if let detailData = data{
            print("detaildata", detailData)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let jsondata = try decoder.decode([Dates].self, from: detailData)
                gameData = jsondata //Hier .instantie wil doen krijg ik ook een error
               
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }catch let error{
                print(error)
            }
        }else{
            print(error!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly does your error occur?

Comment: It occurs at: let jsondata = try decoder.decode([Dates].self, from: detailData).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please learn to understand the decoding error messages, they are very descriptive.

The error says you are going to decode an array but the actual object is a dictionary (the target struct).

First take a look at the beginning of the JSON

```
{
  "copyright" : "NHL and the NHL Shield are registered trademarks of the National Hockey League. NHL and NHL team marks are the property of the NHL and its teams. © NHL 2018. All Rights Reserved.",
  "totalItems" : 2,
  "totalEvents" : 0,
  "totalGames" : 2,
  "totalMatches" : 0,
  "wait" : 10,
  "dates" : [ {
    "date" : "2018-05-04",
```

It starts with a `{` which is a dictionary (an array is `[`) but you want to decode an array (`[Dates]`), that's the type mismatch the error message is referring to.

---

But this is only half the solution. After changing the line to `try decoder.decode(Dates.self` you will get another error that there is no value for key `copyright`.

Look again at the JSON and compare the keys with the struct members. The struct whose members match the JSON keys is `Initial` and you have to get the `dates` array to populate `gameData`.

```
let jsondata = try decoder.decode(Initial.self, from: detailData)
gameData = jsondata.dates
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I ran into some keyNotFound errors now but I'll try to fix them on my own! I am relatively new to swift so any help is welcome! Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

The JSON is represented by your `Initial` struct, not an array of `Dates`.

Change:

```
let jsondata = try decoder.decode([Dates].self, from: detailData)
```

to:

```
let jsondata = try decoder.decode(Initial.self, from: detailData)
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct Answer is done previously from my two friends

but you have to do it better i will provide solution for you to make code more clean and will  give you array of Dates

here is your model with codable

```
   import Foundation

struct Initial: Codable {
    let copyright: String
    let totalItems: Int
    let totalEvents: Int
    let totalGames: Int
    let totalMatches: Int
    let wait: Int
    let dates: [Dates]
}

struct Dates: Codable {
    let date: String
    let totalItems: Int
    let totalEvents: Int
    let totalGames: Int
    let totalMatches: Int
    let games: [Game]
}

struct Game: Codable {
    let gamePk: Int
    let link: String
    let gameType: String
    let season: String
    let gameDate: String
    let status: Status
    let teams: Team
    let venue: Venue
    let content: Content
}

struct Status: Codable {
    let abstractGameState: String
    let codedGameState: Int
    let detailedState: String
    let statusCode: Int
    let startTimeTBD: Bool
}

struct Team: Codable {
    let away: Away
    let home: Home
}

struct Away: Codable {
    let leagueRecord: LeagueRecord
    let score: Int
    let team: TeamInfo
}

struct Home: Codable {
    let leagueRecord: LeagueRecord
    let score: Int
    let team: TeamInfo
}

struct LeagueRecord: Codable {
    let wins: Int
    let losses: Int
    let type: String
}

struct TeamInfo: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let link: String
}

struct Venue: Codable {
    let name: String
    let link: String
}

struct Content: Codable {
    let link: String
}

// MARK: Convenience initializers

extension Initial {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Initial.self, from: data)
    }

}
```

> And Here is Controller Will make solution more easy

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var todaysGamesURL: URL = URL(string: "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule")!

    var gameData: Initial?
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.loadTodaysGames()

    }

        func loadTodaysGames(){
    print("load Games")
    let todaysGamesDatatask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: todaysGamesURL, completionHandler: dataLoaded)
    todaysGamesDatatask.resume()
}
func dataLoaded(data:Data?,response:URLResponse?,error:Error?){
    if let detailData = data {
        if  let inital = try? Initial.init(data: detailData){
           print(inital.dates)
        }else{
             // print("Initial")
        }
    }else{
        print(error!)
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Declaring everything schematically and carelessly as optional **and** ignoring decoding errors with `try?` are very bad suggestions.

Comment: ok my answer updated with your notes, thanks @vadian any more notes from you is appreciated